# Inserting new row into mysql database

Tags: mysql

Im able to create this row:

```
20131115      user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count        {"1":1,"1":2}
```

From this database table:

```
Chart_date      chart_field                 chart_counts
20131115      user_jrFeed_item_count,      {"1":2}
20131115      user_jrForum_item_count,     {"1":1}
```

Now,how can I insert the new row into the existing table and get the result below:

```
 Chart_date     chart_field                                          chart_counts
  20131115      user_jrFeed_item_count ,                              {"1":2}
  20131115      user_jrForum_item_count,                              {"1":1}
  20131115      user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count,       {"1":1,"1":2}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify where you are stuck?

Comment: I want to add the new row I created to the existing database table.I used this code to combine two rows into one.                                                          SELECT Chart_date,GROUP_CONCAT(chart_field )as chart_field,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(chart_counts),'2},{','2,')as chart_counts 
FROM table WHERE Chart_field='' GROUP BY Chart_date                                                             How do I add/insert or merge the row to the data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
INSERT INTO table1(Chart_date, chart_field, chart_counts)
SELECT Chart_date, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(chart_field ) as chart_field, 
       REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(chart_counts),'2},{','2,') as chart_counts 
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY Chart_date
```

Here is **[sQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00592a/1)** demo

Comment: YES...exactly..However for some reason I get {"1":1},{"1":2} on mysql database table...final question how can I rename "user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count," to "songs_file_count"

Comment: @user3011222 It's not very clear do you want to rename a column name or replace a value of `chart_field`?