# Rename table data field in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 Chart_date     chart_field                                          chart_counts
  20131115      user_jrFeed_item_count ,                              {"1":2}
  20131115      user_jrForum_item_count,                              {"1":1}
  20131115      user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count,       {"1":1,"1":2}
```

How can I rename the text "user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count" to something like "song_file_stream_count" in mysql?

The field:  `20131115   user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count,    {"1":1,"1":2}`

is created from this function

```
INSERT INTO table1  (Chart_date, chart_field, chart_counts)
SELECT Chart_date,   GROUP_CONCAT(chart_field ) as chart_field,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(chart_counts),'},{',',') as chart_counts 
FROM table1  
GROUP BY Chart_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields aren't created by that statement. That statement is just inserting into an aggregation table, which is what you asked [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157818/inserting-new-row-into-mysql-database).

Besides, you don't really need to change field names. You are looking for a way to replace the field's values, which is different.

You might run @Aakash Goyal update statement, but keep in mind that any new records created on Chart_date or table1 will come in the current format. You either need to keep updating the records OR just replace them when you query the table.

```
SELECT  Chart_date   ,  
        replace(chart_field, 
                'user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count,',
                'song_file_stream_count') as chart_field,
        chart_counts 
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another column(SrNo) that should act as an auto-incremental one and consider it your primary key. The use the update statement :

```
UPDATE TABLE SET chart_field = "song_file_stream_count" WHERE SrNo = 2;
```

Comment: I'll give it a try...though i know it may affect the other data fields in the actual database.. see this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00592a/1

Comment: It works well....My only fear is that I will be making a major change to the particular table

Comment: Design is very important to avoid such changes, a table without primary keys can be disastrous, especially in SQL.